# Iterate over RDD in apache spark without using collect

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD of POJO values. I need to iterate through values of RDD. But since the volume of data is huge I don't want to use collect.

Is there any alternative approach to iterate RDD values without using collect.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What's the end goal?  Most RDD operations "iterate" the RDD in some way or another.  The most basic one being `map` which applies a function to each element and returns a new RDD with the transformed elements.

Comment: If you are trying to save the RDD of POJO in a persistent store then also you can use `map` function. In that case you won't have to collect all data. But it would be better if you could tell as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are looking for is map or mapPartition transformation of spark.

Please follow the link to get more insights

> http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-map/
>
> http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-mappartitions/